# Some `jar` files do not run in Windows 7

Tags: java, jar, execute

We have bunch of `jar` files that are `Java` applications and run just fine. There are a few however that do nothing although it is expected to run :) with a `GUI`.

Is this a common issue with `jar` files that some have difficulties to run?

The OS is `Windows 7` and the example not working `jar` is [whitebox](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/index.html) a free GIS application, BTW.

We reiterate that we have many `jar` applications that run like a charm in the above system. This means that it should not be a problem with `Java` installation (latest update 7u40 exists in the system).
We checked almost all `jar` failure related topics but no one discussing the issue above which is happening for some applications.
We also mention, we uninstalled and reinstalled `java` many times but with no success. The application `whitebox` does nothing. In one try, it did run and when we closed it. And we are since then trying to run it again but nothing is happening! Even nothing appears in the running `Processes`!

We examined command line and double click. No success. The file type association is correct. Furthermore as we said others are working just fine.

Comment: Memory requirements maybe? Maybe try starting the jar with more memory for the VM (sorry, I forget the syntax of those command line args).

Comment: Have you tried running it in a different OS such as Windows XP or Linux? In how many machines have you tried running the jar in Windows 7?

Comment: @sje397 To report that we just increased `Java` [VM memory](http://www.wikihow.com/Increase-Java-Memory-in-Windows-7) but no success.

Comment: @IgorRodriguez We have only `Windows 7` available for now.

Comment: If you rename the jar file to .zip, will windows open it? I've run into some zip format issues before.

Comment: I have checked that it runs properly on Ubuntu. In Windows XP (in a VM) I get a NoClassDefFoundError exception. Run it through command line, so you can see the stack trace.

Comment: The exception in XP was my bad, I didn't copy the libraries along with the jar. But still doesn't launch.

Comment: @sje397 Indeed, `jar` is a zip file. For the above it opens fine showing two folders `META-INF` and `whiteboxgis`.

Comment: @IgorRodriguez When we run it in `cmd`, it does not run (as it does not in double-click), neither shows any error!

Comment: We have emailed the developer of `whitebox` about this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem reported was due to inadequate `RAM`. `Whitebox` requires **2GB RAM** to run smoothly. While this is huge we could run it on an old laptop with only **1GB RAM**. The solution was to increase the size of ***paging file (virtual memory)*** into the range **1024MB** and **2048MB**. We also moved its location from `C` drive into other drives. We the settings mentioned it runs without any problem. We have tried it many times and happy to report for this case the problem is now completely solved.

**Conclusion:**
For some `Java` applications if something happend as described in the question it may be due to **memory requirement**. In this case increasing virtual memory could solve the problem without a need to buy additional RAM.